# Is there any way to use Content Based Recommendation using flutter as frontend and firebase as backend?

Tags: firebase, flutter, recommendation-engine, content-based-retrieval

I am developing a question answering system app like quora, I want to add content based recommendation to my app so that it can give suggestion while searching question based on users previous seen data and also use the recommendation system for showing the similar content at home page!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no direct way and Firebase don't have any packages for recommendation system but what you can do is use tensor flow to build your own model, train it and integrate it in to firebase ML which also use the firebase cloud function feature. That's it, now use firebase cloud function in your flutter project.